# topojson / D3 / Map with longitude + latitude

Tags: javascript, json, d3.js, svg, topojson

Im using the follwing UK Geo JSON to render a UK SVG Map
http://martinjc.github.io/UK-GeoJSON/json/eng/topo_eer.json

On this map i want to be able to take longitude + latitude points and plot onto the map.

I am adding a GeometryCollection place to the map in the following way:

```
 data.objects.places = {
        type: "GeometryCollection",
        geometries: [
            {
                type: "Point",
                coordinates: [-0.127758, 51.507351], // London
                properties: {
                    name: "London - Testing"
                }
            }
        ]
    };
```

However the coordinates are not in the correct place.

Below is the full javascript.

```
var width = 960;
var height = 1000;

var projection = d3.geo.albers()
        .center([0, 55.4])
        .rotate([4.4, 0])
        .parallels([50, 60])
        .scale(4000)
        .translate([width / 2, height / 2]);

var path = d3.geo.path().projection(projection);

var svg = d3.select("body").append("svg")
        .attr("width", width)
        .attr("height", height);

d3.json("topo_eer.json", function(error, data) {

    // Create path for the UK
    svg.selectAll(".subunit")
            .data(topojson.feature(data, data.objects.eer).features)
            .enter().append("path")
            .attr("class", function(d) { return "subunit " + d.id; })
            .attr("d", path);

    // Path around regions
    svg.append("path")
            .datum(topojson.mesh(data, data.objects.eer, function(a, b) { return a !== b; }))
            .attr("d", path)
            .attr("class", "subunit-boundary");

    // Add places to our data
    data.objects.places = {
        type: "GeometryCollection",
        geometries: [
            {
                type: "Point",
                coordinates: [-0.127758, 51.507351], // London
                properties: {
                    name: "London - Testing"
                }
            }
        ]
    };

    // try plotting a point
    svg.append("path")
            .datum(topojson.feature(data, data.objects.places))
            .attr("d", path)
            .attr("class", "place-online");

    console.log(data);

});
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In a TopoJSON, those numbers in the `coordinates` are not the actual latitude/longitude values. They have to be transformed. This function transforms the quantized topology to absolute coordinates:

```
function transformPoint(topology, position) {
    position = position.slice();
    position[0] = position[0] * topology.transform.scale[0] 
    + topology.transform.translate[0],
    position[1] = position[1] * topology.transform.scale[1] 
    + topology.transform.translate[1]
    return position;
};
```

You'll find the `scale` and `translate` at the end of the TopoJSON you linked:

```
"transform":
    {"scale":
        [0.000818229038834542,0.0005946917122888551],
    "translate":[-6.418556211736409,49.8647494628352]
    }
```

Based on that function, I believe it's easy to write a function that does the reverse:

```
function transformPointReversed(topology, position) {
    position = position.slice();
    position[0] = (position[0] - topology.transform.translate[0])
    /(topology.transform.scale[0]),
    position[1] = (position[1] - topology.transform.translate[1])
    /(topology.transform.scale[1]) 
    return position;
};
```

I tried this function I just made and your London coordinates returned me this array:

```
[7688.309645789168, 2762.1059840278253]
```

Please, test it in your `coordinates` to see if it works.

An alternative is overlaying your TopoJSON with a GeoJSON, which does use an absolute coordinates system.

Here is the API reference: https://github.com/mbostock/topojson-specification/blob/master/README.md#22-geometry-objects

Comment: Ive put this in and im getting the same coordinates as you however its not in the correct position based on the map.

Comment: Did you try `[7688.309645789168, 2762.1059840278253]` for London?

Comment: Running the long / lat though the function produces the same numbers as above and its in the same place 'near the midlands' :(

Comment: Sorry just had another look and it seems it does completely work. I think the transform data you pasted above didnt match the transform data within the file i have which is why it was offset. Thanks very much for the help

Comment: hey, @Peter I, this seems to be London to me: http://jsfiddle.net/gerardofurtado/qkhm405s/1 . And it's the same data!